# What to add as extra starch for a burger?

Tags: hamburgers, starch

A classic burger consists of a beef patty, some salad/ tomato/ onion, a burger bun and some sauces. That already has all the components of a well balanced reasonably healthy meal but a typical burger bun doesn't provide much starch. The classic solution is to take an order of fries on the side. That works but I'm looking for something I can add as an extra layer to the burger.

My first thought was to make a double burger with a beef patty and a vegan burger patty but the vegan patties are usually high in protein because they try to imitate the meat.

What are good options to add as an extra layer in my burger to make the burger a more balanced meal?

Comment: Hi quarangue, I am afraid that we, as other StackExchange sites, can only take quesitons which have an answer that is objectively "right". Questions which ask what to add to a food generally don't fit that requirement - there are dozens of possible answers, and none is objectively better than the others, the choice is dictated by personal taste.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be a hash brown - that's mainly potato, so starchy and tasty.  It's like putting the fried in the burger.  You could also add another layer of bread of some sort, as in some commercial double burgers.

If you actually want to get closer to dietary guidelines, you'll need to up the veg. Veggie/vegan burgers are quite variable, so check the labels if you're buying them.  Bean burgers for example have a fair bit of carbohydrate as well as being a decent source of protein.